# Get info using class and object from file

Tags: python, class, object, file-handling

I have this code which is working fine as intended. But I want to know if is it possible to extract same information from the CSV file saved in main.py for a particular row. For ex. if a user want to know who works in IT department by using the "class" and "object" method from the saved csv file. how can we do that or is it even possible? Thank you

```
class person:
  name = "name"
  email = "email"
  deptt = "deptt"
  def __init__(self,name,email,deptt):
    self.name = name
    self.email = email
    self.deptt = deptt

  def staff(self):
    return f" this person name {self.name} and id is {self.email} and she works in {self.deptt} department "

p1 = person("Hannah","hannah.jones@lycos.com", "admin")

print(p1.staff())
```

Comment: load data and parse

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) to read CSV files.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv')
```

Comment: thank you @david190810. With pandas, I can read file but I want to extract specific info from there so how do we do that?

Comment: For example, you have CSV with two columns, "name" and "email", if you want to find out the "email" of all people named "David", you can do:
`print(df[df['name'] == 'David']["email"])`. The rest you can google.